# Old flask (1.0) app server won't start. How to run or update?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

A few years ago I built an app using Flask 1.0.1 and some packages in their current versions at the time, as shown in the requirement.txt file:

```
alembic==1.0.2
certifi==2018.11.29
dominate==2.3.5
enum34==1.1.6
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Admin==1.5.3
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-Migrate==2.3.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
Mako==1.0.7
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
numpy==1.15.4
python-dateutil==2.8.0
six==1.12.0
SQLAlchemy==1.2.17
visitor==0.1.3
Werkzeug==0.14.1
WTForms==2.1
psycopg2==2.7.6.1
pandas==1.1.0
plotly==4.8.2
```

At the time I deployed it to heroku and was fully functional although only with demonstration purposes (then, heroku started charging and it was deleted). Recently I tried to run it locally creating a python environment using the requirements.txt file but it failed to install some of the packages. I tried installing the packages manually and even though the app did not raise any error, the server simply did not start. I read somewhere that there were some changes in recent versions of flask that changed the way apps are run, but I'm not sure about it.

Since I developed the app for an organization (it's not mine anymore), I cannot give you the full repository, but I'll try to describe its structure:

```
├── DMMexico.py
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── errors.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── modelosdm2.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   └── style.css
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   └── img
│   │       ├── logo_conacyt_md.png
│   │       ├── logo_izt_md.png
│   │       ├── logo_lab_md.png
│   │       └── logo_uami_md.png
│   └── templates
│       ├── 404.html
│       ├── 500.html
│       ├── about.html
│       ├── agregar_hb.html
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── colonia.html
│       ├── consultar_curp.html
│       ├── consultar_sujeto.html
│       ├── index.html
│       ├── login.html
│       ├── medicion_hb.html
│       ├── perfil.html
│       ├── register.html
│       ├── result.html
│       ├── result_hb.html
│       └── territorial.html
├── app.db
├── config.py
├── logs
│   └── errors.log
├── migrations
└── requirements.txt
```

The main file is DMMexico.py, which only contains: `from app import app`

The app folder contains the **init**.py file, which contains:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import os


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'

bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

admin = Admin(app)

from app import routes, models, errors

if not app.debug:
    if not os.path.exists('logs'):
        os.mkdir('logs')
    file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/errors.log', maxBytes=10240, backupCount=10)
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'))
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.info('Sitio deteccion')
```

When I try to run the app using: `python DMMexico.py`, the server simply don't start, although there is no error. Only something like the following is printed in the terminal:

```
[2024-01-16 21:36:15,063] INFO in __init__: Sitio deteccion
```

which is created in the last section of the **init**.py file (`if not app.debug:`).

I'm not a developer. I built the app following some tutorials everywhere just for fun and to learn something, so that's why I have no clue about how to make it work. I have no idea about how to debug it since not even the server is launched and therefore, I cannot see any error in the browser. Any help would be really appreciated.